# Strange pointer warning while printing directory listing

Tags: c

I have the following code to print the directory listing in unix.

```
struct dirent *res;
struct DIR *dir;
scanf("%s",str);
dir=opendir(str);
if(dir==NULL)
{
    perror("Invalid directory");
    return 1;
}
res=(struct dirent *)readdir(dir);
while(res)
{
    printf("%s\n",res->d_name);
    res=(struct dirent *)readdir(dir);
}
```

When I compile the above code I get the following warning

```
ls.c:16:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘readdir’ from incompatible pointer type   
      [enabled by default]
/usr/include/dirent.h:164:23: note: expected ‘struct DIR *’ but argument is of type 
     ‘struct DIR *’
ls.c:20:21: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘readdir’ from incompatible pointer type  
    [enabled by default]
/usr/include/dirent.h:164:23: note: expected ‘struct DIR *’ but argument is of type 
    ‘struct DIR *’
```

What does GCC exactly mean when it says "Expected argument `foo` but argument is of type `foo`"?

I also tried using `struct DIR dir` instead of `*dir` and `&dir` instead of `dir`,but it results in following error

```
ls.c:7:12: error: storage size of ‘dir’ isn’t known
```

PS:The output of the code is perfectly OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DIR is a macro which generally expands to `struct something`, so you're declaring `struct struct something *dir`. Which is apparently a confusing thing to do (though, also apparently, fine by GCC), leading to a confusing error message. The solution is simply to declare `DIR *dir`, without the `struct`.

Comment: Incidentally, I was sufficiently intrigued that I looked up the relevant syntax... in C99, at least, `struct struct foo` is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Ben has the correct solution to your problem, but this does look like a serious problem in how gcc reports this error.

First of all, it wasn't a macro issue. `DIR` is a typedef for `struct __DIR` (at least that's what it is here, and I get the same error message). There is no `struct DIR` except the one declared by `struct DIR *dir;` but gcc seems to be saying there is another type with that name.

This sample compilation unit demonstrates the problem more clearly:

```
struct foo {
  int a,b,c;
};

typedef struct foo bar;

void do_bar(bar *);

void func(void)
{
  int i = 0;

  /* do_bar wants a bar *, which is a struct foo *, but we're giving it an
     int * instead. What will gcc say? */
  do_bar(&i);
}
```

gcc reports:

```
t.c: In function ‘func’:
t.c:15:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘do_bar’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
t.c:7:10: note: expected ‘struct bar *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
```

but there is no `struct bar` in the code at all. It has taken the `bar` typedef and crammed the word `struct` in front of it for no reason.